# Multiplying values from two Access tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have two tables as below in Accecss 2007.

```
Town Table
----------
TownName | FlatCount | DetachedCount | SemiCount
A        | 5         | 3             | 4
B        | 2         | 6             | 3

Cost Table
----------
Prop     | PCost
Flat     | 10
Detached | 20
Semi     | 30
```

I would like to get an output like below by multiplying the Count from the Town table with the corresponding PCost in the Cost table.  `FlatCost = Town.FlatCount * Cost.PCost` for a flat.

```
Results
-------
Town | FlatCount | FlatCost | DetachedCount | DetachedCost | .....
A    | 5         | 50       | 3             | 60           |
B    | 2         | 20       | 6             | 120          |
```

I have tried to do this by using IIF, but not sure how to get PCost for each property type within the IIF clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subquery to retrieve the cost of an item:

```
select  TownName
,       FlatCount
,       FlatCount * (select PCost from Cost where Prop = 'Flat') as FlatCost
,       DetachedCount
,       DetachedCount * (select PCost from Cost where Prop = 'Detached') 
            as DetachedCost
,       ... 
from    Town
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are mixing data and meta data e.g. the data value `Flat` in table `Cost` becomes metadata value (column name) `FlatCount` in table `Town`. This is not a good idea and is probably why you are having difficulties writing what should be a simply query.

Restructure your `Town` table so that it has columns `TownName`, `Prop` and `PCount`. And remember that most bad SQL DML is caused by bad [SQL DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) ;)

Comment: Unhelpful astronaut architect talk, -1

Comment: @Andomar: I'm just not understanding banter at all well today. Give us it slower.

Comment: You are right.  That's how my query design started (with a simple inner join) and then realised how bad the table design was.  The example is a simplified version of a much more complex one designed by an ex employee. :(

Comment: @Sivakanesh: so should you mop the floor or fix the leak?

Answer (score 1):

You have to cross join the tables. Then, for good values, put PCost in the multiplication, else, put 0.

You can then do a SUM using a Group by :

```
SELECT t.Town, 
       t.FlatCount, 
       SUM(t.FlatCount * IIF(c.Prop = 'Flat', c.PCost, 0)) AS FlatCost,
       t.DetachedCount,
       SUM(t.DetachedCount * IIF(c.Prop = 'Detached', c.PCost, 0)) AS DetachedCost,
FROM Town t, Cost c
GROUP BY t.Town, t.FlatCount, t.DetachedCount
```

Comment: I think using the subquery is slightly better than using the `IIF` in Access. Find it hard to manage in complex queries.

Comment: +1, nice solution, probably more efficient than the subquery approach :)